# C - execvp() interprocess communication

Tags: c, pthreads, fork, ipc, pipe

Hi all I am new to C so sorry if I am very lost. I am having trouble with this multi-threaded web server I am trying to create. I am attempting to...

- have a thread create a new thread
- have that new thread execute execvp() to call a different C program on my machine
- have that new thread return streams of data from the execvp()

I was thinking about using pthreads to spawn a new process to run execvp() and have it return the data through a pipe. But is that even necessary? Don't pthreads share memory?

Also, I was maybe thinking about using fork() instead of a pthread and have the child send data back to the parent through a pipe.

Can you please help guide me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a combination of `fork()`, one of the `exec` functions, and `pipe()` (or maybe `socketpair()` or something, but pipes work too).

Threads share memory, but `execvp()` would create a completely new process replacing the caller process -- and even if this process shared memory with its parent (which I'm not sure it does!), the newly run program wouldn't know how to use that memory.

The proper way is to open a pipe when you still have one process, `fork()` into two processes (parent and child), and have the child call `execvp()`. The child can now write into its end of the pipe, and the parent can read from the other end.

Remember to `wait()` for the child to end.

Comment: ah thank you. so how does execvp() work exactly. if the child calls execvp() will it become the program that execvp() calls, or will it spawn another thread that runs execvp seperately and just wait for execvp to finish then join. not sure if that even makes any sense or if that even matters in this case, im just curious

Comment: When a process calls any of the `exec` functions, that process itself becomes the called program. That's why it's rarely called from the parent process. So yes, it's like the first case you described ("if the child calls execvp() will it become the program that execvp() calls").

Comment: Also, you can go to a shell and type `man 3 exec` for more info. Or check it here: http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man3/exec.3.php

Answer (score 1):

Have you written your non-blocking, single-threaded web-server yet? How would you expect to measure the benefits of multithreading if you don't have something to compare it against? It's far easier to determine where the best performance gains are if you expose a single-threaded project to concurrency, than it is to guess and suffer with a poor framework for the rest of the project's life.

Creating threads is easy, but you really need to read the [pthread_create manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html) first. How else can you trust that your project is handling errors correctly? I also suggest reading about [the other pthread functionality](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html). I'm happy to help you resolve issues if you show me that you're trying to resolve them yourself, by the way. I won't bother spoonfeeding you.

As mentioned by aaaaaa123456789, you wouldn't want to spawn using pthread_create/execvp as this would replace your entire program environment (including *all* of your threads) with the new process.